# Can i restore a backup from 20.04 in version 18.04?

Tags: dual-boot, backup

I have a dual boot windows + ubuntu 20.04. I'm thinking of downgrading ubuntu to 18.04 by reinstalling the OS,is it possible for me to do a backup in my current 20.04 which I will recover in an 18.04 or will it be incompatible?

Before I do anything I need some expert opinion to give me recommendation of how to downgrade ubuntu to 18.04 while retaining my files, apps and anything that I have installed from apt-get.

Comment: I would just re-install using *something-else*, selecting your existing partitions & ensure you don't format. The results of this will vary on applications you use and changes that occurred in those apps, but this method allows you to upgrade to a later release, or go backwards to an earlier release. The issue with backwards is earlier programs may have trouble with data files written by later versions of the same app; where I've had mail where I'd used a later feature be ignored by the earlier system as it didn't know how to handle the later flags; mail was on disk but MUA ignored it.

Comment: Back up your data thoroughly as always. That is the only thing that matters. Reinstalling the software you need as you go is not a big issue. I would hesitate reinstalling the older version without wiping the system files of the newer version.